# How to catch focusIn and focusOut events on JSTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am using jsTree with hotkeys plugin to navigate through the tree. I need to implement functions that will be invoked when tree gets focus or loses it. I`ve tried the following jQuery events

- `blur`
- `focus`
- `focusin`
- `focusout`
- `focusout`

but they work incorrectly.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: jsTree Demo Page ->  -> Under Section -> Doing something when a node is clicked -> is this what you looking for focusIn.

Comment: I reckon that OP is after mouse over not clicking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('jstree_selector').bind('set_focus.jstree', function () {
    alert('focus');
}).bind('unset_focus.jstree', function () {
    alert('blur');
});
```